# setCapability() can be called using FirefoxOptions() and DesiredCapabilities object, what's the difference and where to use whichone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set some capabilites on firefox.
I see that using firefox object and DesiredCapabilities object we can do the same thing. What's the difference in both and how to choose which one to use. We can call the same method setCapability() with both objects.

Set the capabilities which were running successfully. But i am confused in options and DesiredCapabilities. What is the difference and relation in both.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

options.setCapability();

DesiredCapabilities desiredCap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

desiredCap.setCapability();
```

Answer (score 2):

DesiredCapabilities is the old way of doing things and is currently deprecated.  The Options pattern is the new way of doing things and has come into Selenium as part of the work of moving the API across to the new W3C compliant API.

```
  /**
   * @deprecated Use {@link #FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions)}.
   */
  @Deprecated
  public FirefoxDriver(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
    this(new FirefoxOptions(Objects.requireNonNull(desiredCapabilities, "No capabilities seen")));
  }
```

Link to the above code [on Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.java#L133)

In Selenium 4 all of the deprecated methods *should* be getting removed (Of course in practice they may not all be removed straight away) so I would suggest you move over to using FirefoxOptions instead of DesiredCapabilities.